# notebook does not boot up after fixing the screws

Tags: boot, laptop

I realised, that sometimes the notebook will start by pressing the power button and sometimes it would not. Then I decided to open the screws one by one and found out that the outerbody screws posed a problem. If I remove them, then the notebook works, and if they are in, then there just a flash of power button led.

My question, if proper grounding may be the solution to the problem? But I am unable to justify this, because normally mobile devices, anyways are not grounded because they run on batteries.

In my setup, I do not have any ground, because the notebook is being supplied power by a variable power supply that only has two wires. Can this be an issue?

The closest, I could find is something related to this post - [Laptop does not boot after unusual static discharge?](https://superuser.com/questions/277588/laptop-does-not-boot-after-unusual-static-discharge). I tried to reset the bios by holding down 15 seconds, but unfortunately I do not get a feedback if its a success or not?

Comments would be really helpful.

EDIT 1- after further inspection .

the problem is definetly the screws that connect the lower body and the upper body. BY simply inserting a naked wire through the screw hole between the upper body and the lower body causes the problem of not booting the laptop anymore. That means, I do not even have to tighten and thereby crush anything. Is it possible that an original charger with neutral, live and earth will solve this problem?

Comment: You've pulled, broken or crushed a ribbon connector somewhere.

Comment: The need to be grounded doesn’t change just because it’s a mobile device.  Laws of electricity doesn’t change.  It wouldn’t be earth ground unless plugged in.  A screw touching the wrong path with a screw or connecting the wrong path to another path can cause your problem.

Comment: "Is it possible that an original charger with neutral, live and earth will solve this problem?" - What laptop make and model, and what power supply are you using? We need more details. However this sounds more like a hardware issue to me, something at that screw hole is shorting out when a screw (ie. conductor) is in that location.

Comment: A loose alumimiium foil above the screw was shorting the lowerbody with the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments.

After further inspection, I found out that there was one aluminium foil ( flexible ) washer that had come loose from inside. Every time, the outer screws were tightened, the aluminium foil will touch the motherboard. When the screws werent tightened, it just missed the motherboard by a mm or so.

After removing the foil, the notebook works, without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that one of the screws is touching a cable and shorting it to ground.
Try removing the screws one at a time to find the culprit.
When you find it, open the laptop to see if there are any wires or cables it may be touching.